# Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 49: parser error : Double hyphen within comment magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I am trying to create a extension with name Kz_Gridlayout. Everything is working but when I try to run SQL by setup.php I get following error. my extension run fine on windows but not working on ubuntu.

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 49: parser error : Double hyphen within comment: <!-- <customer_account>

<!  in /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php on line 444

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/myproj...', 444, Array)
#1 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(444): simplexml_load_string('getFileLayoutUpdatesXml('frontend', 'default', 'mobileshoppe', '4')
#3 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(347): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchFileLayoutUpdates()
#4 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(246): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->fetchPackageLayoutUpdates('default')
#5 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php(224): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->merge('default')
#6 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(306): Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Update->load()
#7 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(109): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayoutUpdates()
#8 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#9 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#10 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#11 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#12 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /var/www/myproject/src/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /var/www/myproject/src/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /var/www/myproject/src/index.php(93): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

here is my XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Kz_Gridlayout>
            <version>0.1.0</version>    
        </Kz_Gridlayout>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <gridlayout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Kz_Gridlayout</module>
                    <frontName>gridlayout</frontName>
                </args>
            </gridlayout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
         <models>
            <gridlayout>
                <class>Kz_Gridlayout_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>gridlayout_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </gridlayout>
            <gridlayout_mysql4>
                <class>Kz_Gridlayout_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <gridlayout>
                        <table>gridlayout</table>
                    </gridlayout>
                </entities>
            </gridlayout_mysql4>
        </models> 
         <resources>
            <gridlayout_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Kz_Gridlayout</module>
                    <class>Kz_Gridlayout_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </gridlayout_setup>
            <gridlayout_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </gridlayout_write>
            <gridlayout_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </gridlayout_read>
        </resources> 
        <blocks>
            <gridlayout>
                <class>Kz_Gridlayout_Block</class>  
            </gridlayout>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <gridlayout>
                <class>Kz_Gridlayout_Helper</class> 

            </gridlayout>
        </helpers>
    </global>
      <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <gridlayout module="gridlayout">
                 <title>Grid Layout</title>
                <sort_order>81</sort_order>              
                <children>
                    <items module="gridlayout">
                        <title>Manage Grid Layout</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                    <action>gridlayout/adminhtml_gridlayout</action>
                    </items>
                </children> 
            </gridlayout>
        </menu>

        <layout>
            <updates>
                <gridlayout>
                    <file>gridlayout.xml</file>
                </gridlayout>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml> 
</config>
```

Comment: Please put all config.xml file to check the issue..

Comment: serach the tag in  <!-- <customer_account> in layout.xmls.

Comment: Amit has the correct answer, you have invalid characters in your layout.xml for the module you have and those characters are `--` just as the error message says.

Comment: but it is working fine on my window's system..

Comment: got it..
you are right @AmitBera

Comment: Strange because I don't see any comments or hyphens in the posted XML.